# split by new line in text file python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, split, newline

i want to print one line from my text file into new lines. i also need it to have labels.

here's how its supposed to work:

my text file has the line

```
Jane Doe Los Angeles Tokyo October 1, 2019 12pm
```

i want to print it like:

```
passenger name: Jane Doe

departure city: Los Angeles

destination: Tokyo 

travel date: October 1, 2019

travel time: 12pm
```

so far i have only succeeded in printing the whole line from the text file

```
    infile = open('reservation.txt','r')
    name = input('Enter passenger name: ')
    date = input('Enter date of travel: ')
    reservations = infile.readlines()

    for line in reservations:
        if name and date in line:
            print(line)
            break

    infile.close()
```

Comment: How are you supposed to differentiate each field? Specifically, Los Angeles is one city but two words. So separating by words won't be enough.

Comment: This will be almost impossible without some sort of seperation marks like `;`or `-`

Answer (score 0):

You have to combine departure city and destination.After that remove name,date and time from list.Best i can suggest is that:

```
infile = open('reservation.txt','r')
name = input('Enter passenger name: ')
date = input('Enter date of travel: ')
reservations = infile.readlines()


for line in reservations:
    y = line.split()
    if name and date in line:
        for names in name.split():
            y.remove(names)
        for dates in date.split():
            y.remove(dates)
        last= y[-1]
        y.remove(y[-1])
        from_where= ""
        for i in y:
            from_where += i + " "
        print("passenger name: {} \nfrom-where {} \ntravel date: {} \ntravel time: {}".format(name,from_where,date,last))
        break
infile.close()
```

Comment: why remove name, date and time from list? btw thanks for answering! it works!

Comment: How will you choose "from_where" ? It might be Boston not Los Angeles. I mean you don't know lenght of "from_where". If you remove the knowns from list you will have the unknown right?